# Is there any way to disable LookUp (Dictionary, Thesaurus) Mac functionality on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, web-deployment

I am developing a vocabulary test website using react js, where a word is given and the meaning should be found and written by the user to the input box. However, with the Mac OS system, the "quick lookup" functionality users can find the definition of the word very easily. So is there any way to disable that function using any programming language, especially using Javascript, or any other ways that can be implemented to my project? Any help would be highly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a OS specific functionality, not related to the Browser at all, so **no, you can't disable it with JavaScript**.